# Pass button value to function in component

Tags: angular

I have a button that gets its value and text dynamically from a component. Upon click of the button, I would like to pass the value to a function in the component.

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" 
value="{{ actionButton.value }}"
(click)="doSomething()">{{ actionButton.text }}</button>
```

```ts
doSomething() {

//Get value from the button clicked.
//Do something with it.

}
```

Is there a way to pass the event?

Comment: `(click)="doSomething(actionButton.value)"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to your methods.

```html
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" 
    value="{{ actionButton.value }}"
    (click)="doSomething(actionButton)">{{ actionButton.text }}</button>
```

```ts
doSomething(actionButton: {value: any}) {
  console.log(actionButton.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So...

currentComponent.component.ts has `public actionButton: {}` ?

currentComponent.component.html has `<button (click)="doSomething()"></button>` ?

if currentComponent is your component &  is not in an *ngFor loop then why would you pass actionButton.value to the DOM to give it back to the component as argument?

You could simply do `doSomething(): void { // do something with actionButton.value }`

If `actionButton` is given to you via `@Input()` the logic remains the same.

Comment: The button generation is in a *ngFor loop

Comment: My bad. doSomething(value: typeOfYourValue): void {} and in html: doSomething(actionButton.value)

Comment: Assuming *ngFor="let actionButton of actionButtons"
And.. you can attribute bind over string interpolation with [value]=actionButton.value over value = {{actionButton.value}}